# How to detect when a React Native app is closed or force close

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to detect my react native app when it closed. So far I have found that
[@react-native-community/hooks](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#useappstate)

but it is not working...
I have used AppState but it only works in foreground and background state but does not work in quit state [React Native AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate.html)

How can i detect my application in quit state ?

I have tried AppsState and [@react-native-community/hooks](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#useappstate)